# Trying to execute GNS3 in Fedora and got a exception AttributeError

Tags: python, fedora16

The exception message is the following:

**Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GApp'"in bound method VBoxManager._*del*_ of GNS3.VBoxManager.VBoxManager object at 0x2591fd0>> ignored**

Before this happened, i'd installed VirtualBox on Fedora. Trying to fix this issue i decided to uninstall VBox, but the problem persisted.